# Creating menus within menus

Tags: html, menu

I'm working on a website at the minute for a project I am doing. I need to create a dropdown menu within a dropdown menu. It is part of a form. Basically its for damage to a car. In my drop down menu I have options for no damage and damage. When I select damage I need it to bring me to another form where I can select the part of the car and type in the damage. THen it needs to save. I may have worded this badly. If anyone can give me any help thta would be great
Here is what I have at the moment

```
    Damage:<br>
  <select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
   <option value="0">No</option>
   <option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none;"><br>
<input type='textarea' class='text' name='hidden style' value size='20' />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(select){
   if(select.value==1){
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "block";
   } else{
    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = "none";
   }
} 
</script><br><br>
```

This gives me a text box to enter the damage into. What I would really like is to be able to get another form whcih gives me further options to select from if this is possible

eg right front
rear left

Comment: If you share the code from what you have tried that would be also great :)

Comment: Hi there - we would need a lot more information on what code you currently have working, and what's not functioning as expected. [Some suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to help us reproduce your problem.

Comment: Check out [Stu Nicholl's CSSPlay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/), for example this one might be for you: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-responsive-multi-level-menu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create 3 level of `ul`

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><span>Level 1-A</span>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Level 2-A-1</span>
            <ul>
                <li><span>Level 3-A-1</span></li>
                <li><span>Level 3-A-2</span></li>                   
                <li><span>Level 3-A-3</span></li>                                       
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Level 2-A-2</span></li>
        <li><span>Level 2-A-3</span></li>            
        <li><span>Level 2-A-4</span></li>            
    </ul>
</li>
<li><span>Level 1-B</span></li>
<li><span>Level 1-C</span></li>
<li><span>Level 1-D</span></li>
<li><span>Level 1-E</span></li>
```

Here is an example of nested dropdown menu, hope it helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wss5A/